# Como restringir el acceso de un usuario a un grupo de recursos

Tags: azure

En la empresa tenemos una suscripción en Azure, y ahora necesitamos permitir acceder a nuestro portal a un usuario de un proveedor externo.
La idea es que pueda gestionar los recursos (crear, eliminar, modificar,...) que están asociados a un grupo de recursos en concreto.
¿Cómo podemos hacer esto?
He estado examinado la opción de Access control (IAM) y no veo una forma clara de hacerlo.

Comment: Aqui puedes encontrar información respecto a lo que estas buscando Enlace correcto.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-external-users